# How to pass data from Vuejs to vuex Store?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a vuejs component and a vuex store.

I would like to send data from vue component to vuejs store and then call a function in vuex that's push data to a db.

I get the data from currentUser (that works), but in vuex store I get the error: `Cannot read property 'push' of null`.

I run `createPost` that works but the data does not pushed to vuex store I think because the error above.

```
#vuejs component
import { mapState, mapGetters, mapMutations, mapActions } from "vuex";
import {
  SET_NEWPOST,
  ADD_TAGS,
  SET_USERDATA,
  SET_GENERAL
} from "@/store/posts/mutations";

methods: {
  ...mapMutations("posts", {
    updateInformation: SET_NEWPOST,
    setUserData: SET_USERDATA,
    addGeneral: SET_GENERAL,
    addTags: ADD_TAGS
  }),

  ...mapActions("posts", {
    create: "triggerAddProductAction"
  }),

  async createPost() {
      this.updateInformation({
        content: this.content,
        url: this.newOne
      });
      this.updateUserData();

      this.createOne();

  }
}
```

vuex  store

```
...
const state = {
  products: []
}    

const mutations = {
   [addProduct]: (state, product) => state.products.push(product)
},

const actions: {
  createUserProduct: async ({ commit, rootState }, product) => {
    const userProductDb = new UserProductsDB(
        rootState.authentication.user.id
    );

    const createdProduct = await userProductDb.create(product);
    commit("addProduct", createdProduct);
 },
 triggerAddProductAction: ({ dispatch, state, commit }) => {
    const post = state.newPost;
    dispatch("createUserProduct", post);
 }
}
```

Comment: You pass the data as the second parameter to `dispatch`, for example to pass a value of `1` use: `this.$store.dispatch('createUserProduct', 1)`

Comment: yeah I understand, but does not helped me

Comment: `const post = ..` is empty and I don't know why

Comment: I think it is because of the way you formatted the object

Comment: I tested different ways but each time the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your format I believe is a little off. Try building the store like this. Remember that using arrow functions vs non-arrow functions can also have a side effect in what is being referenced.

Mostly what can be seen, is that I removed the `const`'s, and placed it all in the object literal directly. I also remove the `Destructuring` of `addProduct` as it doesn't seem logical here.

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    products: []
  },
  mutations: {
    addProduct: (state, product) => {
      state.products.push(product)
      console.log('Added Product:', product)
      console.log('products', state.products)
    }
  },
  actions: {
    async createUserProduct({ commit }, product) {
      commit("addProduct", product);
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  store,
  mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch('createUserProduct', 1)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/3.1.0/vuex.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Are you sure that it is referencing this `push`? Do you have a push somewhere else?

Comment: it is the only one I have in vuex

Comment: I have updated the answer, and the code works, as you can see if you run it. There must be something else that you are doing that is setting the value of `products` to `null`.

Comment: yeahh I think too. Your example explain it in a good way, I changed my code but same error again :/

Comment: Is it possible that `UserProductsDB` or `userProductDb.create()` is manipulating the value somehow?

Comment: ohh it's working now. I forgot to set `products = []` I had `products = null`

Answer (score 1):

I think one of the main problems here is actually that you call mutations directly in your component. Mutations should **always** be called by actions and not directly. This is because mutations are synchronous and actions can be asynchronous. From Vuex docs:

> On to Actions
>   Asynchronicity combined with state mutation can make your program very hard to reason about. For example, when you call two methods both with async callbacks that mutate the state, how do you know when they are called and which callback was called first? This is exactly why we want to separate the two concepts. In Vuex, mutations are synchronous transactions:

```
store.commit('increment')
// any state change that the "increment" mutation may cause
// should be done at this moment.
```

> To handle asynchronous operations, let's introduce Actions.

That's why you should have a structure like this:

```
export const mutations = {
  ADD_EVENT(state, event) {
    state.events.push(event)
  },
  SET_EVENTS(state, events) {
    state.events = events
  },
  SET_EVENTS_TOTAL(state, eventsTotal) {
    state.eventsTotal = eventsTotal
  },
  SET_EVENT(state, event) {
    state.event = event
  }
}
export const actions = {
  createEvent({ commit, dispatch }, event) {
    return EventService.postEvent(event)
      .then(() => {
        commit('ADD_EVENT', event)
        commit('SET_EVENT', event)
        const notification = {
          type: 'success',
          message: 'Your event has been created!'
        }
        dispatch('notification/add', notification, { root: true })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        const notification = {
          type: 'error',
          message: 'There was a problem creating your event: ' + error.message
        }
        dispatch('notification/add', notification, { root: true })
        throw error
      })
  }
```

Check also this video out by vuemastery even featured on the official vuex docs: https://www.vuemastery.com/courses/mastering-vuex/intro-to-vuex/